# Regular Expression replace specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

Does anyone know of a better / cleaner way to write the following:

```
GetSafeTagName(txtUserInput.text);

public static string GetSafeTagName(string tag)
{
    tag = tag.ToUpper()
    .Replace("'","`")
    .Replace('"','`')
    .Replace("&", "and")
    .Replace(",",":")
    .Replace(@"\","/"); //Do not allow escaped characters from user
    tag = Regex.Replace(tag, @"\s+", " "); //multiple spaces with single spaces
    return tag;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: wow, I didn't even know that site existed, I will ask over there thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321331/replace-multiple-string-elements-in-c-sharp) is a SO question where the answer recommends using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I once read an article by Jesse Liberty that said the decent support structure actually slowed the code down........

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression and `Dictionary<string, string>` to do the search replace:

```
// This regex matches either one of the special characters, or a sequence of 
// more than one whitespace characters.
Regex regex = new Regex("['\"&,\\\\]|\\s{2,}");

var map = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "'", "`"},
    { "\"", "`"},
    { "&", "and" },
    { ",", ":" },
    { "\\", "/" }
};

// If the length of the match is greater that 1, then it's a sequence
// of spaces, and we can replace it by a single space. Otherwise, we
// use the dictionary to map the character.
string output = regex.Replace(input.ToUpper(), 
    m => m.Value.Length > 1 ? " " : map[m.Value]);
```

Comment: As elegant as it may seem, sadly this alternative is 3 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do something similar, I used a `Dictionary<string, string>` to define the replacements.

And then something like this to replace:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in replacements)
{
    str = str.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is pretty readable and clean as it stands.  However, if you want to simplify the method itself, I have a decent support structure that would do so and possibly speed it up for particularly long strings:

```
internal static class SafeTag
{
    private static readonly List<Replacement> replacements = new List<Replacement>
    {
        new Replacement("'", "`"),
        new Replacement("\"", "`"),
        new Replacement("&", "and"),
        new Replacement(",", ":"),
        new Replacement("\\", "/")
    };

    private static readonly Regex spaces = new Regex("\\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static string GetSafeTagName(this string tag)
    {
        var parse = new StringBuilder(tag.ToUpper());
        replacements.ForEach(replacement => parse = parse.Replace(replacement.Original, replacement.ToReplaceWith));
        return spaces.Replace(parse.ToString(), " ");
    }

    private struct Replacement
    {
        private readonly string original;

        private readonly string toReplaceWith;

        internal Replacement(string original, string toReplaceWith)
        {
            this.original = original;
            this.toReplaceWith = toReplaceWith;
        }

        internal string Original
        {
            get
            {
                return this.original;
            }
        }

        internal string ToReplaceWith
        {
            get
            {
                return this.toReplaceWith;
            }
        }
    }
}
```